# AutoMapper IncludeBase() not working with generic typeof parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Maybe I'm missing something obviuos, but it seems like `.IncludeBase()` does not work if used with `typeof()` version of parameters.

This works (`LedgerEntryPersistent.Timestamp` is mapped to `LedgerEntryModel.Time`):

```
this.CreateMap<TimedExchangeBoundPersistent<String>, TimedExchangeBoundModel<String>>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Time, mo => mo.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp));

this.CreateMap<LedgerEntryPersistent, LedgerEntryModel>()
    .IncludeBase<
        TimedExchangeBoundPersistent<String>,
        TimedExchangeBoundModel<String>>();
```

This, with the exact same types, **does not** work (`LedgerEntryModel.Time` is not mapped):

```
this.CreateMap(typeof(TimedExchangeBoundPersistent<String>), typeof(TimedExchangeBoundModel<String>))
    .ForMember("Time", mo => mo.MapFrom("Timestamp"));

this.CreateMap(typeof(LedgerEntryPersistent), typeof(LedgerEntryModel))
    .IncludeBase(
        typeof(TimedExchangeBoundPersistent<String>),
        typeof(TimedExchangeBoundModel<String>));
```

I need the `typeof()` version in order to use open generics (for other types than `<String>`).

A runnable example: https://gist.github.com/modo-lv/0bb3b679812872d376aa8a80f74b4f66

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in AutoMapper 6.2.0: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2333

Until the new version is released, see ASpirin's answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The problem not in the `IncludeBase` but in `MapFrom` function
if you'll do

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase<String>, DestinationBase<String>>()
    .ForMember("Time", mo => mo.MapFrom("Timestamp"));
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .IncludeBase<SourceBase<String>, DestinationBase<String>>();
```

The problem will stays

Actually

```
.ForMember(x=>x.Time, mo => mo.MapFrom("Timestamp"));
```

is not working

Try to made Base mapping with a generic function and Child mapping with `string` function

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase<String>, DestinationBase<String>>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.Time, mo => mo.MapFrom(s=>s.Timestamp));
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Source), typeof(Destination))
    .ForMember("Y", mo=>mo.MapFrom("X"))
    .IncludeBase(typeof(SourceBase<String>), typeof(DestinationBase<String>));
```

### Update

create a base function, that will have all base mappings

```
IMappingExpression<SourceBase<T>, DestinationBase<T>> 
         GetBaseMap<T>(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)            
{
    return cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase<T>, DestinationBase<T>>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Time, mo => mo.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp));
}
```

and use it for each predefined child type you want to map

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(StrSource), typeof(StrDestination)); // + specific mappings
GetBaseMap<string>(cfg)
    .Include(typeof(StrSource), typeof(StrDestination));
```

### Update 2 (Expression in `MapFrom`)

Also you can use `MapFrom` version with `Expression` as parameter. Build the expression with:

```
public Expression<Func<object, object>> MapValue(string name, Type sourceType)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var objectParameter = Expression.Convert(parameter, sourceType);
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(objectParameter, name);
    var propertyConverted = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(propertyConverted, parameter);
}
```

usage

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(SourceBase<String>), typeof(DestinationBase<String>))
    .ForMember("Time", 
        mo => mo.MapFrom(MapValue("Timestamp", typeof(SourceBase<string>))));
```

Comment: Can't use generic CreateMap<>, because SourceBase<> needs to work with any type parameter, not just String.

Comment: Don't you have child classes, that you want to map?

Comment: Yes, and each child class can use a different generic type of base class. `Child1 : SourceBase<String>`, `Child2: SourceBase<Int64>`, `Child3: SourceBase<CustomClass>` and so on. I need mapping that can ignore the type parameter and map the Time[stamp] property, which doesn't change.

Comment: Means you have to do `cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IntSource), typeof(IntDestination))` and `cfg.CreateMap(typeof(StringSource), typeof(StringDestination))` and so on, correct? or there are some dynamic mapping build tool?

Comment: I want to avoid repeating the same mapping over and over. `Timestamp` -> `Time` is the same property in all cases, if I have 15 versions of `SourceBase<>`, I don't want to write 15 times `.ForMember(x=>x.Time, mo => mo.MapFrom(s=>s.Timestamp));`

Comment: Not sure you can, because `cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IntSource), typeof(IntDestination))
    .IncludeBase(typeof(SourceBase<String>), typeof(DestinationBase<String>));` will not work

Comment: `MapFrom` in `Type` form can take also an `Expression`, I'll try to build it and share a code if I'll get it done